# Re-evaluate property in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm working in C#-WPF.

I made my own UserControl, a simple cross. With coordinates, I can draw a X on an image.

Parameters are :

- CenterPoint : center for the cross
- Foreground : color for the cross
- Thickness : thickness for the cross

My Cross.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl"
             x:Class="Project.Cross">
    <Grid>
        <Line Stroke="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}"
              StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness, ElementName=userControl}"
              X1="{Binding X1, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}"
              X2="{Binding X2, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}"
              Y1="{Binding Y1, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}"
              Y2="{Binding Y2, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}" />

        <Line Stroke="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}"
              StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness, ElementName=userControl}"
              X1="{Binding X2, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}"
              X2="{Binding X1, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}"
              Y1="{Binding Y1, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}"
              Y2="{Binding Y2, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My Cross.xaml.cs :

```
public partial class Cross : UserControl
{
    public Cross()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public readonly static DependencyProperty CenterPointProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CenterPoint",
        typeof(PointF), typeof(Cross),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(PointF)));

    public PointF CenterPoint
    {
        get { return (PointF)GetValue(CenterPointProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CenterPointProperty, value); }
    }

    public readonly static DependencyProperty ThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Thickness",
        typeof(int), typeof(Cross),
        new PropertyMetadata(2));

    public int Thickness
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThicknessProperty, value); }
    } 

    public float X1
    {
        get
        {
            return (float)(CenterPoint.X - (Width / 2));
        }
    }
    public float X2
    {
        get
        {
            return (float)(CenterPoint.X + (Width / 2));
        }
    }
    public float Y1
    {
        get
        {
            return (float)(CenterPoint.Y - (Height / 2));
        }
    }
    public float Y2
    {
        get
        {
            return (float)(CenterPoint.Y + (Height / 2));
        }
    }
}
```

I can call it like :

```
<local:Cross CenterPoint="{Binding Point}" Thickness="8" Foreground="Yellow" Height="40" Width="40"/>
```

I have a problem, the cross is not displayed. I added breakpoints, it seems that the values X1,X2,... does not refresh when I change the CenterPoint. How can I force C# to re-evaluate theses values ? (hope this solve my problem)

Thank you

Comment: Could you show the xaml in which the local:Cross is defined?  eg what is it contained within ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I showed the file Cross.xaml where I define the UserControl `Cross` in my local namespace.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you don't just draw the cross as a fixed sized based on width and height of user control and then move that object around whatever you're drawing it on by setting its position relative to the target object.  So I was wondering what you are drawing the cross on.

Comment: `X1` etc. need to be "read-only dependency properties", and you need a `PropertyChanged` handler on `CenterPoint` which updates them. As it is, you do something which will have the effect of changing the values returned by `X1` etc., but you keep it a secret. *The whole point of a Doomsday Machine is lost if you keep it a secret!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mm8's method will work for updating `X1` etc., but there are additional issues that need to be addressed to make the control work.

I'm using an alternate way to update the coordinate properties: Make `X1` etc. into [read-only dependency properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754044(v=vs.110).aspx), and have your usercontrol update them when `CenterPoint` changes and when the control's size changes.

I've also changed your winforms `PointF` to a WPF's `System.Windows.Point`, which uses `double` for `X` and `Y`, and I've changed `Thickness` to `float` as well, because WPF uses `float` for line thickness and you may as well take full advantage.

I'm updating the coordinates on the `SizeChanged` event, which is critical, since otherwise, the coordinate properties will only be set on control creation when the actual size is 0 x 0, and `Width` and `Height` are `NaN`.

Finally, you should be using `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`, which are updated "live" unlike `Height` and `Width`, which are design-time attribute values. If you give it a fixed `Width` and `Height`, the effect will be the same; using `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` allows it to stretch to fit a container if that's desired.

```
public partial class Cross : UserControl
{
    public Cross()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SizeChanged += Cross_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void Cross_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateXYProperties();
    }

    protected void UpdateXYProperties()
    {
        X1 = (float)(CenterPoint.X - (ActualWidth / 2));
        X2 = (float)(CenterPoint.X + (ActualWidth / 2));
        Y1 = (float)(CenterPoint.Y - (ActualHeight / 2));
        Y2 = (float)(CenterPoint.Y + (ActualHeight / 2));
    }

    public readonly static DependencyProperty CenterPointProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CenterPoint),
        typeof(Point), typeof(Cross),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(Point), CenterPoint_PropertyChanged));

    private static void CenterPoint_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Cross)obj).UpdateXYProperties();
    }

    public Point CenterPoint
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(CenterPointProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CenterPointProperty, value); }
    }

    public readonly static DependencyProperty ThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Thickness),
        typeof(float), typeof(Cross),
        new PropertyMetadata(2.0F));

    public float Thickness
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(ThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    #region Read-Only Properties
    #region X1 Property
    public float X1
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(X1Property); }
        protected set { SetValue(X1PropertyKey, value); }
    }

    internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey X1PropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("X1", typeof(float), typeof(Cross),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0F));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty X1Property = X1PropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    #endregion X1 Property

    #region X2 Property
    public float X2
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(X2Property); }
        protected set { SetValue(X2PropertyKey, value); }
    }

    internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey X2PropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("X2", typeof(float), typeof(Cross),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0F));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty X2Property = X2PropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    #endregion X2 Property

    #region Y1 Property
    public float Y1
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(Y1Property); }
        protected set { SetValue(Y1PropertyKey, value); }
    }

    internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey Y1PropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("Y1", typeof(float), typeof(Cross),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0F));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Y1Property = Y1PropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    #endregion Y1 Property

    #region Y2 Property
    public float Y2
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(Y2Property); }
        protected set { SetValue(Y2PropertyKey, value); }
    }

    internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey Y2PropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("Y2", typeof(float), typeof(Cross),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0F));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Y2Property = Y2PropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    #endregion Y2 Property
    #endregion Read-Only Properties
}
```

Lastly, you don't need to explicitly make your bindings `Mode=OneWay`, because `Line.X1` etc. can't update the binding source (that's your own `X1` etc. in this case), and so they're already `OneWay` by default.

```
<Grid>
    <Line 
        Stroke="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}"
        StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness, ElementName=userControl}"
        X1="{Binding X1, ElementName=userControl}"
        X2="{Binding X2, ElementName=userControl}"
        Y1="{Binding Y1, ElementName=userControl}"
        Y2="{Binding Y2, ElementName=userControl}" 
        />

    <Line 
        Stroke="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}"
        StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness, ElementName=userControl}"
        X1="{Binding X2, ElementName=userControl}"
        X2="{Binding X1, ElementName=userControl}"
        Y1="{Binding Y1, ElementName=userControl}"
        Y2="{Binding Y2, ElementName=userControl}"
        />
</Grid>
```

Lastly, and almost certainly least: The effect of the `CenterPoint` design will be to offset the cross outside of the control's bounds if it isn't the actual center of the control. If that was your intent, don't bother reading the rest of this paragraph. If that was not your intent, you could rewrite `UpdateXYProperties()` as follows and lose the `CenterPoint` property:

```
protected void UpdateXYProperties()
{
    X1 = 0;
    X2 = (float)ActualWidth;
    Y1 = 0;
    Y2 = (float)ActualHeight;
}
```

But that's up to you and St. Andrew.

Comment: I have tried this solution but I can run my application. There is a XmlParseException with something like "Constructor for cross has rise an exception".

Comment: @A.Pissicat Can I see your actual code that produced that exception? Mine isn't doing that.

Comment: I found the error. `PropertyMetadata(0.0)` was not considered has a float. I replaced these instruction by `PropertyMetadata(default(float))` and I have no error. I still can't see my cross but I can run my project. I'm searching why they are not displayed.

Comment: @A.Pissicat Ah! OK, I fixed that in my code before I ran it. Sorry, my bad! I've added some updates, one of which fixes that float literal issue (I'm using `0.0F` now), and a few fixes for things that were preventing the X from being shown. Try what I've got now.

Comment: I'm very disappointed, it works better but no perfectly.  I created a cross like this : `<local:Cross x:Name="CrossTest" CenterPoint="{Binding SelectedItem.Point1}" Thickness="2" Foreground="Aqua" Height="20" Width="20"/>`. When application start I have a cross (finally \o/). But when my class SelectedItem (containing 4 points) change, nothing append. I've try to add a event mouse up to try : `CrossTest.CenterPoint = e.GetPosition(MyImage);`. Now when I click, my cross disappears.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `CenterPoint_PropertyChanged` and see what the new value of `CenterPoint` is. Also, are you raising `PropertyChanged` correctly when `SelectedItem` changes and when `SelectedItem.Point1` changes?

Comment: My cross is in center of screen. I think that C# put my user control has a 20x20 box. When I click In image I set Cross out of the range. The only way to get it back is to click on top left corner but it goes on center.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't set Cross out of the range. I have no idea what that last sentence means. Top left corner of what, center of what? Maybe you're doing the wrong thing in some Click handler I haven't seen? Can't guess. ---- What is your fundamental goal here? Are you trying to put a cross in a box? Why do you have `CenterPoint` designed to draw the X outside of the control?

Comment: "I think that C# put my user control has a 20x20 box.": What does that mean and why are you guessing about it? The code's right there in the editor, isn't it?

Comment: I created 2 properties for CrossHeight and CrossWidth. Now it works good. Thank you for your help, and sorry for my bad explanations. Now I can set a cross and my image and when I click, the cross goes on the click location. I did not expect such a simple thing to be so complicated to code.

Comment: Ohhh, it's supposed to go where you click! Now I get it. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the bindings to the X1, X2, Y1 and Y2 read-only properties to get refreshed when the CenterPoint dependency property is set to a new value the UserControl should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You could then register a `PropertyChangedCallback` for the dependency property and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the read-only properties:

```
public partial class Cross : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Cross()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public readonly static DependencyProperty CenterPointProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CenterPoint",
        typeof(PointF), typeof(Cross),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(PointF), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCenterPointUpdated))));

    private static void OnCenterPointUpdated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Cross cross = d as Cross;
        cross.NotifyPropertyChanged("X1");
        cross.NotifyPropertyChanged("X2");
        cross.NotifyPropertyChanged("Y1");
        cross.NotifyPropertyChanged("Y2");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    ...
}
```